# Html.TextArea value/text not updating after page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textarea

I am working in MVC 5 and i have a HTML.TextArea that has an initial value on page load. It loads up correctly but if you type anything in the textarea or change anything, the value doesn't update in the DOM. I can look at the page source and it doesn't change. I also tried HTML.TextAreaFor to try a binding approach but that also failed to update any changes to the initial value. I can't find anything on google for this issue so hopefully someone can shed light on this odd behavior. I avoid TextArea's like a plague so knowledge is limited with them.

```
@HTML.TextArea("MyTextArea","My Test Text")
```

Loads "My Test Text" and then if you type "but it no work!" The DOM/Postback value will not be updated with added text, returns ("My Test Text")

Comment: Why do you avoid Textareas like the plague? lol

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that you are overwriting the value of `MyTextarea` within your controller and passing it back to the view?

Comment: The initial value of the TextArea is hard set like in the example i did. It has nothing to do with the controller or the Model for the View. The value of the TextArea just simply will not update when you start changing the text. The work around is to use jQuery and grab the value of the TextArea and then update the .html property of the text area with its own value....so stupid but it does work.

Comment: Oh, so your textarea is locked in the UI?  Something must be adding a `disabled` attribute to it, or something in your javascript is preventing the editing.  Does it work if you disable all Javascript for the page, or edit the DOM to call jQuery `$('input').prop('disabled',false)` on it from the console?

Comment: Also, just so that I'm understanding you correctly.  The value of a textarea or text box won't update IN THE DOM when you update it.  It will update on the screen only, not in the actual DOM, only what was originally rendered will appear in the DOM unless changes are made to the DOM using JavaScript/jQuery or by editing it manually within the developer tools or something.

Comment: Yea, If i use HTML.TextAreaFor instead which means it populates from a property on my Model. It still fails to update the textarea when you change the initial value. I am having to manually update the innerHTML of the control with it's own value via Jquery so that the change is reflected on the DOM.

Comment: Yep that is corrrect :) Thus why i am using the jQuery work around. Just curious to why the DOM doesn't update itself. Similar to a Textbox does, you edit the value of a textbox, it reflects instantly on the DOM. The textarea however does not. -_-

Comment: Are you sure you dont have the MyTextArea element twice in the form? Sounds to me like you have a hidden one and a visible one and the form is submitting the hidden value.

Comment: You don't need the DOM to update.  If you use jQuery to get the current value of the textarea using $('#yourtextareaid').val() it will reflect the current value, not the value displayed in the DOM.

Comment: A textbox doesn't update instantly in the DOM as far as I can see.  But as long as you can use JavaScript to get the updated value of the textbox/textarea and when you submit the form it submits the updated value, then that's fine isn't it?

Comment: Yea the value updating isn't the issue, i needed the DOM to update because i am grabbing the HTML for a screen capture. Since the textarea's html wasn't updating live on the DOM, i had to use jQuery to update the DOM so that when i did the screencapture, it captured the updated TextArea's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the following elements...

```
<input type="text" value="My Text" />
<textarea>My Text</textarea>`
```

...the **HTML** will reflect what was originally rendered even if they are updated by the user using the browser's UI.

The updated values of these elements will be reflected if the form is `POST`ed or if you attempt to get the value for the textarea/text box using jQuery such as:

```
var currentTextareaValue = $('#yourtextareaid').val()
```

It's worth baring in mind that there is a difference between the **DOM** and the **HTML** output.  Here's the definition of the DOM from Google:

> The Document Object Model (DOM) is a cross-platform and
>   language-independent convention for representing and interacting with
>   objects in HTML, XHTML, and XML documents. The nodes of every document
>   are organized in a tree structure, called the DOM tree.

The DOM is updated, but not the HTML output unless you make changes to the this specifically such as an update to the value attribute of a textbox or the value between the `<textarea>` tags:

```
// Update the textbox value
$('#yourtextboxid').attr("value", "new value");

// Update the text area value
$('#yourtextareaid').html("new value")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar problem, but with pure JavaScript, html and css.

In case someone was trying to update `document.getElementById("<textarea id>").innerHTML = <text>;` it should be `document.getElementById("<textarea id>").value = <text>` instead.

JavaScript was able to update `.value` after user typing in the `textarea` no problem.

Both cases do allow user typing in the `textarea`, but JavaScript was having trouble updating the `.innerHTML` after user manipulated the `textarea`.