# ASP.NET Web Forms: Make an external API Request and display response on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've found a lot of posts for ASP.NET Web API but nothing at all for classic Web Forms. I want to call an external API and display its result on a web page text field. But even though the API call is successful, the response is not received (or at least not shown on the page.

**C# code behind:**

```
protected void btnOptimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Optimize();
}

public async Task Optimize() {
  string URI = "https://EXTERNAL_API_BASE_URL/POST";
  string auth = "Bearer XXXX";

  var client = new HttpClient();

  MyData data = new MyData();
  data.text = "Hello world";

  string requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

  var stringContent = new StringContent(requestBody);

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);

  var response = await client.PostAsync(URI, stringContent);

  //display on page's text field
  txtResponse.Value = response.Content.ToString();
}
```

**ASP.NET Page:**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <textarea runat="server" id="txtInput"></textarea>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOptimize" runat="server" OnClick="btnOptimize_Click" Text="Generate" />
            <textarea runat="server" id="txtResponse"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

What should I do differently? Should I add an UpdatePanel to my ASP.NET page?

Comment: Have you tried that external API call in `Postman` and did you get a data response?

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist Yep! API is all good. It's just that I'm probably not displaying or managing the page state properly

Comment: Okay so if that is out of the way then take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504915/html-textarea-value-text-not-updating-after-page-load). Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Read the HttpClient's response with **ReadAsStringAsync()**

```
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Please see [HttpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

Since the Optimize method is async, try changing the code like this.

```
//First change the method so it's async as well.
protected async Task btnOptimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //Then call the Optimize() method using the await keyword.
  await Optimize();
}

public async Task Optimize() {
  string URI = "https://EXTERNAL_API_BASE_URL/POST";
  string auth = "Bearer XXXX";

  var client = new HttpClient();

  MyData data = new MyData();
  data.text = "Hello world";

  string requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

  var stringContent = new StringContent(requestBody);

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);

  var response = await client.PostAsync(URI, stringContent);

  //display on the page's text field
  //You should get value using the await keyword.
  //response.content also has a method called ReadAsStringAsync(),
  //it should be visible if you are using intellisense in VisualStudio
  txtResponse.Value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```